# O(n) or O(n)^2 time complexity of the algorithm?

Tags: algorithm

What is the time complexity of the following algorithm?

```
int j = 0;
while (j<n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        x++;
        j++;
    }
}
```

I tried it and calculated it like this: n*n = n^2, so result would be O(n)^2.

But I have second thoughts that it could also be like this: n+n= 2n. Result: O(n).

I know that if you have two `for` loops, you should multiply your n's. But here we have `while` and `for`, so I don't know.

Comment: Run the code and see what X is after you're done.  That'll give you your answer.

Comment: If you have an exam in two days, then surely you have a text book you could consult, or a professor or a classmate you could ask.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on cs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @thirtythreeforty That's not an explanation of why it *doesn't* belong on SO.  Questions are closed because they're not suitable for the site that they're on, not because they might be suitable for another site.  That said, the question wouldn't even be an appropriate question on CS.SE (at least as it sits).  You shouldn't be directing low quality questions to other sites where they're just going to get shot down there as well.

Comment: Ok guys I wanna know why the question is innapropriate... How should I ask question like that then?

Comment: It's not something that you usually see here in SO. It's not anything that doesn't work or an error.. it's just a basic question about Big O theory. It's ok to ask and it's ok to not know something. (However this are not the questions that we're used to see here)

Comment: this question did not deserve 10 downvotes

Answer (score 2):

it is actually just O(n).. (not O(n+n), not O(2n), not O(n^n), just O(n) )
because since you increment `j` up to `n` in the inner loop
as soon as you finish the inner loop of `n` elements, the outer condition will be false.. so it will exit, after `n` iterations

Comment: Right! you can test it pretty easily putting a "WriteLine" inside the while loop (but not inside the for loop) it will write just once :)

Answer (score 1):

I think your understanding of determining time complexity with programs involving loops is a bit off. The general approach is to count the **number of iterations**. The complexity of the generic program:

```
Loop until SomeCondition:
    DoStuff()
```

Is `O([#iterations]*[complexity of DoStuff])`. So if the number of iterations is proportional to some variable `n` and `DoStuff` is proportional to some variable `m`, then this program is `O(n*m)`.

Circling back to your question: we see that the inner for loop is proportional to the variable `n`. Now we ask ourselves "How many iterations does it take for the while loop to reach its condition?". Well that depends on how much `j` grows each iteration! As pointed out by CaldasGM `j` increases by one for every iteration of the inner for loop. This means that `j` grows by `n` each iteration and so the while loop will exit after one iteration!

So the complexity of this program is `O([#iterations]*[Complexity of loop contents]) = O([1*n]*[1]) = O(n)`.

Hope this helps your understanding :)

Comment: Glad I could help! :)